# How to save text to database tinyMCE

Tags: php, html, mysql, tinymce

How do we save the textarea to SQL?

here is the html:

```
<form method="post" action="text-handler.php">
      <textarea name="content" style="width:100%;cursor:text;"></textarea>
</form>
```

and the php:

```
<?php

session_start();
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
require_once("config/db.php");
require_once("config/db_connection.php");
$newtext = $_POST['content'];
$sql = mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO 'texts' ('text', 'user') VALUES ($newtext, $user_name)");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that identifier quotes are backticks not single quotes:

Here in your code:

```
 INTO 'texts' ('text', 'user')
      ^     ^  ^    ^  ^    ^ // use backticks not single quotes
```

And this query is unsafe, and is directly injecting user input in the statement and prone to sql injection.

Better to use prepared statement instead:

```
session_start();
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
require_once("config/db.php");
require_once("config/db_connection.php");
$newtext = $_POST['content'];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `texts` (`text`, `user`) VALUES (?, ?)';
$insert = $db_connection->prepare($sql);
$insert->bind_param('ss', $newtext, $user_name);
$insert->execute();

if($insert->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo 'insert complete';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am just using this kind of code 
here is the html and ////////

  /

here is the control part 
public function insert_projects_to_db($data)
  {

```
return $this->db->insert('projects', $data);
```

}

fucntion in the data base for sent=ding data to the data base
$pdata['description'] = $this->input->post('description');